# exchange online add user to shared mailbox if he doesn't own a personal mailbox

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory, exchange-online

Is it possible for a Azure AD-User to have no personal Exchange-Mailbox but having a shared mailbox assigned to him? It would be totally ok for this User having an Exchange license attached to his account (so he can be part of the members of this shared mailbox). BUT they would not want to have a personal Mailbox attached, as it shouldn't be used and would clutter their Workspace.

The whole point / background is:
There are several Azure AD Users used to login to a ThinClient, **one User for every VDI**.
BUT they should have only one Mailbox, which is the shared Mailbox.
I have tried to add such a User to the shared mailbox, but it wasn't possible from the admin.exchange.microsoft.com page.

Or should one reconsider the whole setup and login with the same user on several VDIs / ThinClients?

I hope it's half understandable what I try to convey.

Even more background:
I know, we could just login with a different account in outlook. But for some reason, these seperately inserted account-credentials are always invalidated during every update of the VDI. So we can't get the VDI infrastructure to keep these Outlook-only credentials at life after the update. So we need to use the Windows-Account to login to Outlook. Or otherwise, we (the ServiceDesk) needs to reinsert the credentials after every VDI-Update, which is a huge pain, because there are about 600 virtual computers affected each time.